# ShellExecuteEx not working like I expect it to do

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I use the folowing function to start MS Word and open a file. This is done OK but the Word app is not maximized on top of my application. Is that not possible to add to my function?

```
function TFiles.ExecuteAndWait(const aFile: string; aParam: string = ''; const aHidden: boolean = False): integer;
var
  SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0) ;
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo) ;
  with SEInfo do
    begin
      fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
      Wnd := Application.Handle;
      lpFile := PChar(aFile) ;
      lpParameters := PChar(aParam) ;
      if aHidden = True then
        nShow := SW_HIDE
      else
        nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
    begin
      repeat
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode) ;
      until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) Or Application.Terminated;
      Result := ExitCode;
    end
  else
    Result := -1;
end;
```

Comment: Pass `SW_MAXIMIZE` instead of `SW_SHOWNORMAL`?

Comment: If you want the word application to cover your application form, see [How to shell to another app and have it appear in a delphi form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/796883/576719).

Comment: @ LU RD    looks like it does the trick.

Comment: Please, one question at a time, don't pile more questions onto existing ones, I reverted

Comment: I did it because I found out that the second part wasn't posted in first attempt - don't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. Pass `SW_MAXIMIZE` if you want the window to be maximized.
2. You leak the process handle. Call `CloseHandle` when you have finished with the process handle.
3. The busy loop works, but is clumsy. You should use a wait function. Either in a separate thread use `WaitForSingleObject`. Or if you must wait in the main thread, and must use `ProcessMessages`, use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: Eurekalog doesn't report any memoryleaks so it must be another kind of leak you are talking about.

Comment: Have you got an example of option 3?  I am having a bit trouble following you.

Comment: Yes, you are leaking a handle to the process. EurekaLog won't tell you about that. The superior madExcept will!

Comment: As for option 3, which part. There are two distinct approaches suggested to avoid the busy loop.

Comment: MsgWaitForMultipleObjects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334553/processmessages-and-use-of-application/10341681#10341681

Comment: OK - so I should CloseHandle(Wnd)?

Comment: No. Close the process handle. I'm not sure that you really understand the code that you wrote. Have you read the documentation for the api function that you called?

Comment: It isn't my code - I inherited it from a colleague at my last work and haven't really looked at it since it worked - except for the focus.

Comment: It has problems. I'd understand them and fix them if I were you.

Comment: Are you still stuck on this?

Comment: I wouldn't say stuck - I found the process to release. But the waiting is as it has always been. It works but may not be the finest code

Comment: I'm very sorry that you did not find this helpful. I felt that I went beyond the original question but you obviously don't agree.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me - it was helpfull. I found the leak but the waiting I am still working on solving. I just don't have that much time and as I say it works but it could be better.

Comment: You didn't ask about any of that though. That was a bonus. It looks like I should have just answered your original question!

Comment: That you did i item 1 - but LU RD did first

Comment: There's only one answer so far as I can see. Also, do you care who comes first. It's easy to write a single sentence comment. Takes more effort to write an answer like mine. Looks like you care more about a quick answer than the content. That's not right.